# how to give css to action link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

Below is my action link . How shall I apply css to the following? Actually i want to give the class as we do in asp.net simple application. Please tell me what shall I do?

Comment: if you don't accept any answers, people are going to stop answering...

Comment: but not yet! (judging from the answers below)

Comment: Thanks for downvoting me people, Im capable of deleting my answers when better ones come along.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a .net developer, but replace your ActionLink code with this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Forgot password?", "ForgotPassword", new { @class="my_class" })%>
```

And add this to your CSS:

```
.my_class {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You supply HTML attributes as anonymous objects:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Forgot password?", "ForgotPassword", new{ @class="MyCSSClass" })%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Forgot password?", "ForgotPassword", new{ @class="classname" }) %>
```